# Varnish configuration not working

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have been installed varnish module in drupal 7 while clicking on configure it shows an error page with title server error and if i come back to module menu there was another error log

like **Warning: require_once(/var/www/magz/sites/all/modules/varnish/varnish.admin.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in menu_execute_active_handler() (line 515 of /var/www/magz/includes/menu.inc).**

I tried reinstalling and some other stuffs but the error is still there is there any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if the path and file (folder) is valid? seems that the module requires certain file which are not there.

I've checked with version: 7.x-1.0-beta2 and no such issue occurred.

Just to close out that the read permissions would cause this, please follow the instruction from that: [page](http://frizi.net/drupal-server/drupal-file-directory-structure-and-file-persmision-setting) - regarding access rights setting.